# Finding a not constant char.set in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have an NSString with data for ex.:

> {SCENE*169/doprava/doprava_tabulka {} {} {} 1299234095} {SCENE*169/doprava/doprava_video {} {} {} 1299234166}

I would like delete parts "brackests and the number", but the numers are not constatnt.

> {} {} {} 1299234095
>   {} {} {} 1299234166

How can I delete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `NSRegularExpression`

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
                              @"((?: \\{\\}){3} [0-9]+)" options:0 error:nil];
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:
                        @"{SCENE*169/doprava/doprava_tabulka {} {} {} 1299234095} {SCENE*169/doprava/doprava_video {} {} {} 1299234166}"];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

`str` value here is `{SCENE*169/doprava/doprava_tabulka} {SCENE*169/doprava/doprava_video}`

But if you develop for iOS, it's only available since 3.2.

Comment: Can I use something like: @"((?: \\{\\}){3} [0-9]+)" from your code with method: "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:"

It will be easyer. But I can't write the good format of this condition

Comment: No, `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` only replaces constant substrings.